# How to show a pop up on screen of a specifc user in google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to show a **pop-up** when a specific mentioned **user opens the google sheet**. The main idea is to check a specific column for an **email** and **compare** it with the email of the person who opened the google sheet. If the email matches, the pop-up should show on the screen.

```
function onOpen() 
{
  var result = ?
  var email = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  if(result = email) {
    ui.alert('Important Notice');
  }
}
```

I am here so far, I need to get the email from a specific column in the result variable. Let's say column A has the email addresses and when the email address matches the user who opened the sheet, the pop up will be shown to that person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If the question is how to get the contents of all cells in a column:

- You can get all the column contents as an 1-D array by first using the method [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) and then [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).
- You can check either user's email is contained in this array with [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

Sample (please refer to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) for a better understanding othe methods used - if necessary):

```js
function bindMeToAnInstallableOnOpenTrigger() 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Name of the Sheet containing emails");
  var emails = sheet.getRange("A2:A").getValues().flat();
  var email = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  if(emails.indexOf(email) != -1) {
    ui.alert('Important Notice');
  }
}
```

- Note that `getEffectiveUser()` is a call that requires authorization and thus will not work on a [simple](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) `onOpen trigger`.
- Instead, you need to rename your function and bind an [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) `onOpen` trigger to it.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the quick reply. Your answer helped me find the problem with authorization. Moving on, I was trying to run your code and it gave me an error code. 
`
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null
`
I googled this and found out that this could be happening because of the name of the sheet but I have checked it many times, the name is ok and I am kinda stuck in this error to run your code. Although with your help, I made my own code work. Thanks though.

Comment: Hello @AliAhmad. What is your sheet called (please mind upper/lower case and spaces)? You can use `getActiveSheet()` as you did, but mind that if your spreadsheet has more than one sheet and the emails are in a specific sheet with might lead to problems.

Comment: Yes, thank you for directing me to the right path. I am new to app script coding so, I was entering the spreadsheet name instead of the sheet name. You are awesome, man. Thank you for your precious time. I have modified your code according to my problem and for my better understanding and debugging.

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me but the problem is unless and until the user doesn't give permission to it by running the code once, it will not work. So, every user who is added to the sheet needs to run the Appscript once and give it permission. As this [person](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73207008/9450313) said that it needs authorization, so I understand the problem is with my code.

```
function onOpen() 
{
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1:A15');
  var value = range.getValue();
  var email = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  if(value = email) {
    ui.alert('Important Notice');
  }
}
```

**Edited:**

I have modified the code given to me by the mentioned user according to my understanding.

```
function onOpen() 
{
  popup();
}

function popup() 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var emails = sheet.getRange('I20:I70').getValues().flat();
  var email = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var index = emails.indexOf(email);
  if(index > -1) {
    ui.alert('This notification is to inform you that there is a task/issue that is pending');
  }
}
```